# Translate data task function for background upgrade from Swift to Objective C

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, nsurlsessiondatatask

I'm trying to implement a function in AppDelegate.m in order to update my app in background.

I've found an article online (this is the link: https://medium.com/@vialyx/ios-dev-course-background-modes-fetch-70c18f9f58d5) but it's written in Swift and I can't translate it from Swift to Objective C this part of the code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // Create url which from we will get fresh data
    if let url = URL(string: "https://www.vialyx.com") {
        // Send request
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            // Check Data
            guard let `data` = data else { completionHandler(.failed); return }
            // Get result from data
            let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            // Print result into console
            print("performFetchWithCompletionHandler result: \(String(describing: result))")
            // Call background fetch completion with .newData result
            completionHandler(.newData)
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
// Create url which from we will get fresh data
NSURL*url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://www.vialyx.com"];
[[NSURLSession sharedSession ] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (data != nil) {
        NSString* result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        // Print result into console
        NSLog(@"performFetchWithCompletionHandler result: %@",result);
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
    }
    else {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed); 
    } 
  }];
}
```

Comment: can it will be used in background download?

Comment: @Sh_Khan thank you, everything is ok except the NSLog line. Maybe you forgot to insert %@ after the colon.

Comment: okay i don't have idea regarding it. that's why asked. Thanks :)